# Webpack and TypeScript: Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm trying to compile TypeScript using Webpack, but for some reasons it fails on imports:

> ERROR in ./path/to/MySource.ts
>       Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./path/to/MyIncludedFile in ...

despite `MyIncludedFile.ts` is actually there and the IDE can recognise the import too, the TypeScript compiler doesn't find the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running Webpack with `--display-error-detail` I got some extra information:

```
/path/to/MyIncludedFile doesn't exist
/path/to/MyIncludedFile.webpack.js doesn't exist
/path/to/MyIncludedFile.web.js doesn't exist
/path/to/MyIncludedFile.js doesn't exist
/path/to/MyIncludedFile.json doesn't exist
```

because of that, I realised that Webpack wasn't looking for the correct extension, which in my case is `.ts`.

In order to solve that I modified my `webpack.config.js` adding the following:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts']
}
```

inside my module configuration. So to be more specific, my module webpack conf now look like this:

```
module.exports = [
  {
      entry: /* my entry config */
      output: {
          /* my output config */
      },
      module: {
          loaders: [
              {
                  test: /\.ts/,
                  loaders: ['ts-loader']
              }
          ]
      },
      /* ... other stuff ... */
      resolve: {
          extensions: ['.ts']
      }
  },
  /* ... other modules ... */
]
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this error, too and also tried it with `--display-error-details` (in newer webpack versions the parameter has a trailing `s`!).

Turned out I forgot the dots in my extensions array. Adding them resolved the issue.

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
//              ^      ^       ^
//              |      |       |
//           don't forget these dots!
}
```

Sometimes it's the tiny details and a giant error log that leads to the solution, I guess. Hope it helps someone in the future.

Comment: And now  --display-error-details is deprecated see -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999928/webpack-and-typescript-module-not-found-error-cannot-resolve-file-or-direc